# Arduino Leonardo: error exiting bootloader

Tags: arduino

I tried to upload my code to an Arduino Leonardo through  theArduino IDE, but:

```
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = "ю"; type = ё
Software Version = h.; Hardware Version = u.M
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader
```

What is wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: You may have better luck getting an answer at [arduino.se].

Comment: Not a coding problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are some tips:

- This is very often error message when you using damaged cable to upload your code. Try it with another cable.
- If you are using *AVRISP mkII* try to switch to *USBasp*
- Check if you have current version of Arduino IDE.
- Check your circuit. It could effect the communication.
- Go to the Board manager :

[image: Board Manager in Arduino IDE]

Than select latest version of support of your board and click install button.

[image]

- You can try burn new bootloader:

  1. After connect the AVR-USBASP from your computer to the arduino board, open the arduino IDE and click on Tools menu and under the Programmer sub-menu select USBasp. **Be sure that USBasp driver is installed!**

[image: Select USBasp as programer]

2. Then, click on the Burn Bootloader to start burning the bootloader under Tools menu.

[image: Burn boot loader]

3. After few minutes the Arduino IDE should show this message:

> Done burning bootloader

Comment: Thanks, burning new bootloader helped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems it was because the global variables were taking up too much memory space.
I managed the upload through the following actions:
1. Reduce sketch size (<60% dynamic memory is ok)
2. Connect the USB cable just before the upload starts.
Doing this, the problem went away.
(I am using a Leonardo beetle board)